# Logging with two handlers - one to file and one to stderr

Tags: python, logging, error-logging

I have the following code to create two logging handlers. The goal is to have the `stream_handler` write only to the `sterr` and the `file_handler` only to file.

In the code below, `stream_handler` writes to the file as well, so I have duplicate log entries whenever I log a message. How can I modify it to get the `stream_handler` *not* to write to the file?

```
def create_timed_rotating_log(
        name='log',
        path='logs/',
        when='D',
        interval=1,
        backupCount=30,
        form='%(asctime)s | %(name)s |  %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        sterr = False,
        verbose=False):

  logger = logging.getLogger(name)
  formatter = logging.Formatter(form)
  logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

  if sterr:
      stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
      stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if verbose else logging.ERROR)
      stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
      logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

  file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=path+name,
                                          when=when,
                                          interval=interval,
                                          backupCount=backupCount)
  file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
  file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if verbose else logging.ERROR)
  logger.addHandler(file_handler)

  return logger
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure why this is the case but adding the StreamHandler first causes it to also write to the file. I moved the StreamHandler to after adding the TimedRotatingFileHandler and this resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have considered that the messages go to both handlers as duplication.  If you wanted the file not to receive messages and them to only go to stderr, when stderr=True, you never to put the code that adds the file handler in an else so that it is only added if stderr=False

Specifically:

```
if sterr:
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if verbose else logging.ERROR)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
else:
    file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=path+name,
                                          when=when,
                                          interval=interval,
                                          backupCount=backupCount)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if verbose else logging.ERROR)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

I had considered this possible but less likely than the more common issue of setting up handlers multiple times when how you are supposed use logging is that in the main module you add the handlers to the root logger and then only get the logger for the current module via `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. This and `import logging` is the only logging code that should appear in any but the module where `if __name__=="__main__":` occurs where right after that it should setup the logging.

---

The only way you will have duplicates is if you call that function in your program twice. The issue isn't these two handlers but the other two handlers from the second call to this setup function.

You need to just add the handlers once to the root logger not once for every logger in each module.

Comment: I think if you run it with sterr and verbose == True you'll find that's not the case

Comment: How many times does your program call `create_timed_rotating_log`?

Comment: just once... I then use the logger object returned to write messages using .info,debig, etc;

Comment: Looks like you have considered that the messages go to both handlers as duplication.  If you wanted the file not to receive messages and them to only go to stderr, when stderr=True, you never to put the code that adds the file handler in an else so that it is only added if stderr=False